# new to git - how to change directory in git gui

Tags: java, git

when i launch my git gui, if i look at the top left hand corner,  it points to c: i am trying to change this but it does not work

so here is what i tried: I tried to look through [this documentation](http://matthew-brett.github.io/pydagogue/git_gui_windows.html), and it states that when I right click in my folder i want to be a repository on my pc, Iwill find a option called "git init here", no such option exists... how can i make this folder of mine recognized by the git gui ?

Comment: thats why i always prefer git shell rather than GUI

Comment: I am no posting this as answer, because is a little offtopic, but I recommend using the command line to do operations on git repository and the GUI only to visualization of repository states

Answer (score 3):

This will open Git Gui in "my folder":

Open command line and type:

```
cd <my folder>
git gui
```